# Custom roslyn-based inspections in Sonarqube

Tags: .net, sonarqube, roslyn

I want to make custom inspections for Sonarqube using the new roslyn based code analyser. Is that possible?

Comment: It [looks that way as of v3.4](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS/fixforversion/20460)

Comment: stuartd: As of v3.4 of the c#/.net plugin, they use a Roslyn based analyser. But my question is, is it possible to make custom rules for that plugin using roslyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet possible but it will once this ticket will be resolved : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-456

Comment: Do you know where SonarSource will move the JIRA content to?

Comment: The JIRA content will be moved to jira.sonarsource.com. It's done for SONAR JIRAs, the rest will come in coming days. http://jira.codehaus.org/ is now in read-only mode.